# How to call function (shm_open) in librt inside the glibc source code (malloc/morecore.c)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, glibc

I am trying to modify the `__default_morecore` function in `malloc/morecore.c`. The original `__default_morecore` is a simple wrapper for `sbrk`, but I want to use `shm_open` function inside `__default_morecore` to create shared memory object. Here is the `malloc/morecore.c` code I modified:

```
...
/* Include header files for shm_open */

void *
__default_morecore (ptrdiff_t increment)
{
  int shm_fd;
  /* Create the shared memory object */
  shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
  if (shm_fd < 0){
    return NULL;
  }
...
}
```

I am pretty sure that my codes are right since I tested the code snippet in a small program and it works. After making this change, it will show below error message when using `make` for glibc 2.32 sources:

> .../build/libc_pic.os: In function '__GI___default_morecore': 
> .../malloc/morecore.c:69: undefined reference to `shm_open' 
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
> ../Makerules:698: recipe for targe '.../build/libc.so' failed

I searched online for this error, and it's typically becasue doesn't link with `-lrt`. I tried add `-lrt` in 'LDFLAGS' and 'LIBS' during `../configure`, but not working. Then I added `-lrt` at the end of `build-shlib` of `Makerules` (which is used to build `libc.so`), and the error was changed to be following:

> //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_getcpuclockid@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
>
> //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_nanosleep@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
>
> //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_settime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
>
> //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined reference to `__clock_getres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
>
> //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__libc_vfork@GLIBC_PRIVATE' 
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ../Rules:215: recipe for target '/home/yifei/FSL_Repos/test_shm_mmap_malloc/glibc-malloc-modified/build/iconv/iconvconfig' failed

The new error shows that multiple symbols from `librt.so` and `libpthread.so` are undefined. I tried add `-lpthread -lrt` to many places in glibc `Makefile/Makeconfig/Makerules`, but it doesn't work. Also, from the above errors, I found the linking libraries are from my system in-built libraries, not the path of current modified glibc which I am building. Is that an expected behavior? I think it should use the `librt.so` and `libpthread.so` in my modified glibc I am building, but I cannot find `librt.so`, `librt.a` and `libpthread.so` in my `build` folder after the `make` terminates. Does it mean these are not generated at the stage of the error I occur? If yes, it might be a dependency issue considering I called a glibc function inside glibc. **How to resolve that issue?**

**How can I call `shm_open` in `malloc/morecore.c` and link that librt without any error?** Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you do that? Why do you need a shared memory object from a _global shared_ implementation of standard library from morecore? Wouldn't it be easier to just overwrite `__morecore` hook for programs that need it rather then recompiling whole glibc? `undefined reference to` because symbols are resolved in order, would specifying libraries twice `-lpthread -lrt -lpthread -lrt` help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could I specify the modified implementation by `__morecore` hook outside the `glibc` without needs to recompile? If so, that would be more convenient and effective. I tried to use `-lpthread -lrt -lpthread -lrt`, but it doesn't seem to work, and it will still have the same error messages. Can I explicitly specify the shared library path that I would like to link? `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the `-L` option of gcc?

Comment: @KamilCuk That is not going to work. We want the `__morecore` to be overridden at the very beginning, before the first `malloc()` is called. But this can't be achieved if a C++ program has one or more static STL containers (Their constructors may be called first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shm_open` is just a thin wrapper around the `open` function, see `sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c`. What is problematic is the construction of the file name in the `SHM_GET_NAME` macro (in `sysdeps/posix/shm-directory.h`). It calls `__shm_directory` (from `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/shm-directory.c`), and the current implementation potentially calls `malloc` under the covers.

I suggest hard-wiring the shared memory segment location to a file in `/dev/shm`, and call `open` directly (or rather `__open64`, otherwise the linknamespace tests will fail during `make check`).

The `__morecore` hook is not a complete solution because it only covers part of the main allocation arena used by glibc `malloc`. If you want to experiment with `malloc`, it may be easier to start out of with a simple out-of-tree `malloc` implementation and use the [symbol interposition mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html). But you still need to be careful which glibc functions you call in your interposing `malloc`.

Comment: We prevented `malloc()` from doing `mmap()` to request anonymous memory, and we are sure `sbrk()` won't be called. Is that still incomplete? I think custom `malloc` implementation would be complex. If using a trivial one then it can't handle fragmentation issues properly.

Comment: I meant something simpler than glibc `malloc`, like `dlmalloc` or the historic `gmalloc`.